# Best practices for Windows 10 opsec?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm thinking about upgrading my Win7 machine to Windows 10, but current info I'm finding online is contradictory and generally fuzzy about to what extent it phones home and otherwise compromises security. Thus my question:

What steps does one have to take to upgrade Windows 10 from Windows 7 such that:

- You do not have to have an account with Microsoft,
- You can use BitLocker without your Bitlocker recovery key being shared with
  Microsoft,
- And, in general, Windows does not send back any information about you to Microsoft?

Thanks in advance. I'd rather not get halfway or completely through an upgrade only to find out this can't be done. I already know how to install Windows. What I do not know is the full gamut of things that need to be disabled in order to install Windows in a secure manner.

Comment: For the third bullet question, you will find an answer here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98172/what-are-the-privacy-and-security-implications-of-windows-telemetry

Comment: Saw that. It doesn't address all the steps you have to take, though- I'd like to see something a bit more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

> You can use BitLocker without your encryption key being shared with
>   Microsoft,

No, you do not share the encryption key with Microsoft because it is managed by  the Trusted Platform Module ([TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module))  which is usually installed on the motherboard of a desktop or portable computer, and communicates with the rest of the system by using a hardware bus.

> And, in general, Windows does not send back any information about you
>   to Microsoft?

You may read this:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98172/what-are-the-privacy-and-security-implications-of-windows-telemetry

Comment: Then why all the stories about mandatory BitLocker recovery key backup AKA key escrow with Microsoft? I believe this is a valid question under Security- The question is not how to install Windows per se, but what needs to be done in order to do so in a /secure/ manner.

Comment: @schnauss - Can you be more specific than `all the stories`? Perhaps you could add a few links to the original question.